# Has many relationship where parent doesn't have a table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I want to create a `Logger` class that has a `hasMany` relation to `LogEntries`. There only needs to be one `Logger` instance thus I do not wish to create a new table for this and there will be no `logger_id` on the `LogEntry`.

Is it possible in Laravel to have such a relationship?

Comment: please share your code whatever you have tried.

Comment: Can you share the code that you try so far

Comment: You might be able to get this working using service providers and facades rather than eloquent models